# find Device Token Xcode? For Push Notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, device, token, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to find the device token so that i can send push notifications but this is not sending anything to my NSLog.

```
(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
      NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have enabled notifications with the following command?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```